# Classes are missing when Generating Java Binding Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to generate Java Xamarin Binding of 
http://sdk.camera360.com/page/sdk

But however it is not generating all the class. It is building successfully, but classes are missing from generated build. Some classes are abstract and some are simple  class without any access modifier.